# What's the right mouse button on the keypad for Mousekeys?

Tags: windows-7

None of the buttons on the number-pad work for the mouse's right-click button.  What am I doing wrong? I use the keypad as a replacement for a mouse.

Win 7.
IE 9.

Comment: This is a good question. Interestingly, the Control Panel only states  that MouseKeys can be used to "**move** the mouse around the screen" using the numeric keypad. It provides no instructions on how to use it!

Comment: @iglvzx Well, it's only 16 buttons... the adventurous of us just press keys randomly and figure it out! :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[To click by using MouseKeys](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/access_mousekeys_howtoclick.mspx?mfr=true) explains in detail how *MouseKeys* works:

> - To click, press <kbd>5</kbd> on your numeric keypad.
> - To double-click, press <kbd>+</kbd> on your numeric keypad.
> - **To right-click, press** <kbd>-</kbd> **on your numeric keypad, and then press** <kbd>5</kbd> **to click**, or press <kbd>+</kbd> to double-click.
> - To click as if you were using both mouse buttons at once, press <kbd>*</kbd> on your numeric keypad, and then press <kbd>5</kbd> to click, or press <kbd>+</kbd> to double-click.
> - To switch back to standard clicking, press <kbd>/</kbd> on your numeric keypad.

(formatting and emphasis mine)

It's from the Windows XP Professional documentation, but it still applies.

Comment: The Windows 7 documentation is here (from my now-deleted answer): http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer